# Unable to install Search plugin for CakePHP by Friendsofcake

Tags: php, cakephp, search, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakePHP, so this may be a beginner's question.

I am trying to install the Search plugin for CakePHP by Friendsofcake (https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search)

Using the Readme in the above link, I qant to search my **Users** by the fields **email** (varchar) and **RG** (Integer).

But, as I try to visit ../Users the system presents the error by the end of this text.
The error seems to be as if the method **findParams** is not valid, even if the Search plugin is loaded in my bootstrap.php.

I have the following UsersTable.php and UsersController.php:

UsersTable:

```
use Search\Manager;


class UsersTable extends Cake\ORM\Table {

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize();
        // Add the behaviour to your table
        $this->addBehavior('Search.Search');

    }
    // Configure how you want the search plugin to work with this table class
    public function searchConfiguration()
    {
        $search = new Manager($this);
        $search
            ->value('email', [
                'field' => $this->aliasField('email'),
            ])
            // Here we will alias the 'q' query param to search the `Users.email`
            // field and the `Users.rg` field, using a LIKE match, with `%`
            // both before and after.
            ->like('q', [
                'before' => true,
                'after' => true,
                'field' => [$this->aliasField('email'), $this->aliasField('rg')]
            ])
            ->callback('foo', [
                'callback' => function ($query, $args, $manager) {
                    // Modify $query as required
                }
            ]);

        return $search;
    }

}
```

UsersController:

```
namespace App\Controller;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg', [
            'actions' => ['index']
        ]);
    } 

    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }
    }
    public function logout() {
            $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out.');
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->Users
            // Use the plugins 'search' custom finder and pass in the
            // processed query params
            ->find('search', $this->Users->filterParams($this->request->query))
            // You can add extra things to the query if you need to
            ->contain(['rg'])
            ->where(['email IS NOT' => null]);

        $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
    }
}
```

And now i am getting the error:

> Unknown method "filterParams" BadMethodCallException
>
> ⟩ Cake\ORM\Table->__call APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 42 ⟩
>   App\Controller\UsersController->index [internal function] ⟩
>   call_user_func_array
>   ROOT\vendor\friendsofcake\crud\src\Controller\ControllerTrait.php,
>   line 51 ⟩ App\Controller\AppController->invokeAction
>   CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 114 ⟩
>   Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line
>   87 ⟩ Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably meant to change `$this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));` to `$this->set('users', $this->paginate($query));` in your UsersController. Also change `class UsersTable extends Cake\ORM\Table` in UsersTable to `class UsersTable extends Table` - there may be more errors like this for you to check in your code with the standard examples for the plugin.